# Wocoomerce Membership functions return with undefined in any of my child template file

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-memberships

I would like to try using the function below in my `content-product.php` within my child theme
`wc_memberships_get_product_membership_plans()`. But every time I added this, it always return with undefined function `wc_memberships_get_product_membership_plans()`?

Is there anything I need to do prior to using this? My WooCommerce membership is active.

I have tried to add it to functions.php and to `content-product.php`, but nothing works

Comment: You should add `content-product.php` template modified code to your question, better explaining what you are trying to do in details…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, i managed to fix it. 

Cheers,